# Why does mv work so slowly renaming files in my SD card?

Tags: sd-card, rename, pcmanfm, mv

The SD card is in a phone which is tethered to the computer.

```
% pwd
/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A003%2C007%5D/SanDisk SD card
% date && mv f759fdradio_ga_ga.mp3 radio_ga_ga.mp3 && date          
Thu Sep 15 23:29:05 EDT 2016
Thu Sep 15 23:29:31 EDT 2016
```

Using 'rename' to rename the files en-mass works as slowly as mv does.

Using PCManFM to rename the files individually and manually works very quickly (albeit tediously).

Why is mv so slow? And more importantly, is there a way to use PCManFM's renaming function from the shell?

Answer (score 0):

As you see when you are moving the that it is mounted over gvfs which is the gnome virtual file system which pcmanfm, pcmanfm-qt along with many other file managers use and will already have it installed. You could try the gvfs-rename command to rename all the files on the phone. Also if it is still slow you could be filling up your write cache of things to change on the phone as if you still can write in the cache but once it is full it will slow down if you want more information on this see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing). Unfortanetly if it is caching that is causing the first move to be quick but all the rest to be slow. To find out if this is a problem I would try using mv on one file and if that is quite quick per file. Also sd cards in phones are not the fastest storage medium and you need to write the changes to the sd card for each file. For long file transfers I remember pcmanfm having a progress bar is it not moving for each file or are you renaming so many files that it could take that long.